# Cache controller performance in VHDL

Tags: caching, vhdl, simulation

I am designing a cache controller in VHDL as a project. Is there any way to check for its performance i.e., number of memory reads, hit ratio etc?

Comment: Not inherently but it's easy to write.

Comment: So, does that mean using test benches in VHDL to calculate number of memory reads and its corresponding hit ratio for a given cache controller code in VHDL?

Comment: Yes... unless you want to build stats collection into the hardware itself, which is also possible (but some would say, a waste of hardware).

Comment: different people run specf95 suite test for cache design performances. i have seen it in a couple of papers like say for example this paper "Way-Predicting Set-Associative Cache for High Performance and Low Energy Consumption". How do they do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your code yourself. Unless you find something online that somebody else has already programmed. You can just write behavioral (i.e. high-level) VHDL code, with counters and such.
If you don't want the code to be synthesized, you should surround it with with pragma's

```
-- pragma synthesis_off
[your test code]
-- pragma synthesis_on
```

with should work in most synthesis programs. Else try `-- pragma translate_off` and `..._on`.